# How can a get the position of an entity from a HTTP GET /message request in Wit.Ai

Tags: wit.ai

The [Wit.Ai HTTP API Documentation](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#get--message-link) provides a response example for a POST /converse request which returns the "start" and "end" position of an entity, as seen below:

```
{
    "type": "merge",
    "entities": {"location": [{"body": "Brussels",
                               "value": {"type": "value",
                                         "value": "Brussels",
                                         "suggested": true},
                               "start": 11,
                               "end": 19,
                               "entity": "location"}]},
    "confidence": 1
  }
```

There is also a deprecated GET https://api.wit.ai/messages/$MSG_ID request that returns the same information.

Is there a way to configure the GET /message request to return "start" and "end" attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use verbose=true in your request to get the position of your entities.